# Difference between applicative and monadic computation in scala

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative

Given this simple computation i can not clearly see the difference between using applicative style over monadic style. Are there some better examples out there ( in scala ) when to use the one over the other.

```
    println( (3.some |@| none[Int] |@| 4.some )( (a:Int,b:Int,c:Int) => {  a + b + c } )  ) // prints None

    println( for( 
     a <- Some(3);
     b <- none[Int];
     c <- Some(4)
   ) yield( a + b + c ) ) // prints None
```

Both computations ending up in a **None** so the end result is the same. The only difference i can see ist that there is no temporaray access to those vars in the for comprehension when using the applicative syntax.

Furthermore having one None value stops the whole computation. I thought applicative means **"not dependent on the result of the computation before"**

Comment: Maybe you should read the [paper that introduced Applicative](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=1457852&fileId=S0956796807006326). For me, reading the paper made me understand the difference between Monad and Applicative.

Comment: This is hard to read ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The applicative builder syntax will evaluate each term and *can not* use the result of a prior computation. However, even if the first result is None, all the other expressions will still be evaluated.

Whereas, with the for comprehension, it will 'fail fast' (it will not evaluate any further expressions after a None, in your case), plus you can access the results of previous computations.

Don't think of these things as simply different ***styles***, they are calling different functions with different behaviours: i.e. flatMap vs apply

Comment: But in the end the function {  a + b + c } will not be called and so it looks like the same behaviour.

Comment: But each term 3.some, none[Int] and 4.some will be evaluated. Wrap them in something like {println("one"); 3}.some if you need convincing.

Comment: You're right. So i think Option is a bad test case for this.

Comment: Couldn't you implement a fail-fast version of `apply`?

Comment: @ziggystar What u mean by that ?

Comment: But its legal to say the computation of { a + b + c } is dependet on all computations before. If one fails the function will never be called ?

Comment: About your last point: many people argue that for monadic types any implementation of `ap` must be consistent with the one derived from `flatMap`. I don't find this argument entirely convincing, but that's the approach taken by Scalaz and other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Monads represent *sequential* computations where each next computation depends on previous ones (if previous computation is empty you can't proceed, so you "fail fast"), more generic example of monadic computation:

```
println( for( 
     a <- Some(1);
     b <- Some(a);
     c <- Some(a + b)
   ) yield( a + b + c ) ) //=> 4
```

Applicative is just `fmap` on steroids where not only an argument, but a mapping function itself can be empty. In your case it can be rewritten as:

```
4.some <*>
  { none[Int] <*>
    { 3.some <*> 
      { (_: Int) + (_: Int) + (_: Int) }.curried.some } }
```

On some step your function becomes `Option[Int => Int] = None`, but it doesn't stop from applying it to `4.some`, only the result is `None` as expected. You still need to know the value of `4.some`.

Comment: This is equal to `Some(4).flatMap { a => None.flatMap { b => Some(3).map { c => a + b + c } } }` ? Doesn't seem so ciz None.flatMap does not evaluate the mapping function.